# Android: How to develop multiple apps in a single apps?

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk

I am developing some android app. They are about 9 of them. 
I dont want this apps to be seperated or indipendent of each other. I want to them to be in one sigle app but each apps has a different function is carries out.

How do i go about doing this? I just need some guidance. How do i include the other apps in one sigle app, so that it will be on the fone a single app but within it should be multiple different apps, performing different functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Develop on app in which at first screen place 9 item (as per you app no) like grid or as per your choice and on hat item click start activity related to that app.
Like in attached image[image]

For A reference you can install [Libraries for developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos) app in you device and take a look that how then integrated lots of demo app for different different libraries.

Comment: please i did not understand you. I just want a single app with multiple app inside that one sigle app. that is it should acts like a container to ther other other apps.